# Criação de servidor local com express

Tags: javascript, node.js, front-end, back-end

Instalei o framework *express* em minha pasta raiz com todos os projetos em Node, para que fosse fácil importar os modulos em todos os projetos. Porém quando tento iniciar um servidor local, com o seguinte escopo:

```
const reference = require("../node_modules/express");
const app = express();

app.listen(8081);
```

Sempre recebo a seguinte mensagem ao tentar rodar o servidor pelo terminal:

```
C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\Node\serverExpress>node index.js
C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\Node\serverExpress\index.js:9
const app = express();
            ^

ReferenceError: express is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\Node\serverExpress\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Pelo que sei, a função express na linha dois vem junto com a importação do modulo. O que pode estar errado?

Comment: qual a associação entre app e express() eu não estou vendo, vc está atribuindo para app um valor que ele não encontra.

Comment: `const express = require('express');
const app = express();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto está errado:

> Pelo que sei, a função express na linha dois vem junto com a importação do modulo.

Para algo estar disponível em um arquivo ele precisa ser explicitamente importado.

Dito isso, você importa o `express` na constante `reference` mas nunca faz o uso dela. O correto, como mostrado na [Introdução](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/starter/hello-world.html) da documentação, seria:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(8081);
```

Comment: Você está correto Giovane, eu estava tratando o parâmetro express como função, quando na verdade eu devo fazer referência a variável que eu declaro na linha de cima.

Answer (score 2):

Para se iniciar um servidor utilizando o framework express precisamos:
**definir a porta**

```
const porta = 3003
```

**importar o express**

```
const express = require('express')
```

**atribuir ao app ou outra constante de sua preferencia o express**

```
const app = express()
```

**agora podemos olhar a minha-rota no navegador que está utilizando o verbo get nesse caso.**

```
app.get('/minha-rota', (req, res, next) => {
   res.send('alguma coisa')
})
```

**não esqueça de ficar escutando na porta**

```
app.listen(porta, () => {
console.log(`Servidor está executando na porta ${porta}.`)
})
```